# .NET MAUI HorizontalStackLayout Trigger not triggers

Tags: c#, maui

I wanted to create something like a wizard for taking images. I put in the grid vertically 4 HorizontalStackLayout components. After a step a I want to hide the previous and show the next one.
Here is a code, that I am struggling with:

```
            <Grid RowDefinitions="30,40" ColumnDefinitions="5*,1*,1*">
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                    <HorizontalStackLayout x:Name="houseSideSptepOne">
                        <HorizontalStackLayout.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="HorizontalStackLayout"
                                         Binding="{Binding HouseSideSptep}"
                                         Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </HorizontalStackLayout.Triggers>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                               Text="{loc:Localize HouseSide_1}"
                               FontFamily="PoppinsSemibold" TextColor="{StaticResource Gray600}" FontSize="17"
                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                                     Command="{Binding CameraCommand}" CommandParameter="1" 
                                     Source="camera.png" HeightRequest="30" 
                                     WidthRequest="30" Margin="30,0,30,0"
                                     HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
                                     Command="{Binding SideViewImagesGalleryCommand}" CommandParameter="1" 
                                     Source="gallery.png" HeightRequest="30" 
                                     WidthRequest="30"
                                     HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    <HorizontalStackLayout x:Name="houseSideSptepTwo">
                        <HorizontalStackLayout.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="HorizontalStackLayout" 
                                         Binding="{Binding HouseSideSptep}"
                                         Value="2">
                                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </HorizontalStackLayout.Triggers>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                               Text="{loc:Localize HouseSide_2}"
                               FontFamily="PoppinsSemibold" TextColor="{StaticResource Gray600}" FontSize="17"
                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                                     Command="{Binding CameraCommand}" CommandParameter="2" 
                                     Source="camera.png" HeightRequest="30" 
                                     WidthRequest="30" Margin="30,0,30,0"
                                     HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
                                     Command="{Binding SideViewImagesGalleryCommand}" CommandParameter="2" 
                                     Source="gallery.png" HeightRequest="30" 
                                     WidthRequest="30"
                                     HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    <HorizontalStackLayout x:Name="houseSideSptepThree">
                        <HorizontalStackLayout.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="HorizontalStackLayout" 
                                         Binding="{Binding HouseSideSptep}"
                                         Value="3">
                                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </HorizontalStackLayout.Triggers>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                               Text="{loc:Localize HouseSide_3}"
                               FontFamily="PoppinsSemibold" TextColor="{StaticResource Gray600}" FontSize="17"
                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                                     Command="{Binding CameraCommand}" CommandParameter="3" 
                                     Source="camera.png" HeightRequest="30" 
                                     WidthRequest="30" Margin="30,0,30,0"
                                     HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
                                     Command="{Binding SideViewImagesGalleryCommand}" CommandParameter="3" 
                                     Source="gallery.png" HeightRequest="30" 
                                     WidthRequest="30"
                                     HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    <HorizontalStackLayout x:Name="houseSideSptepFour">
                        <HorizontalStackLayout.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="HorizontalStackLayout" 
                                         Binding="{Binding HouseSideSptep}"
                                         Value="4">
                                <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </HorizontalStackLayout.Triggers>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                               Text="{loc:Localize HouseSide_4}"
                               FontFamily="PoppinsSemibold" TextColor="{StaticResource Gray600}" FontSize="17"
                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                                     Command="{Binding CameraCommand}" CommandParameter="4" 
                                     Source="camera.png" HeightRequest="30" 
                                     WidthRequest="30" Margin="30,0,30,0"
                                     HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                            <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
                                         Command="{Binding SideViewImagesGalleryCommand}" CommandParameter="4" 
                                         Source="gallery.png" HeightRequest="30" 
                                         WidthRequest="30"
                                         HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
                <ImageButton Source="checkmark.png" WidthRequest="30"
                             Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
                             HorizontalOptions="End"
                             Command="{Binding NextSideViewCommand}"/>
            </Grid>
```

In the view model I added a property:

[ObservableProperty]
private int houseSideSptep = 1;

Created a command

```
public IRelayCommand NextSideViewCommand => new RelayCommand(ExecuteNextSideViewCommand);
private void ExecuteNextSideViewCommand() => HouseSideSptep++
```

;

In the view's code behind I hided the last three HorizontalStackLayouts.

```
public DetailedDataPage(DetailedDataViewModel DetailedDataViewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = DetailedDataViewModel;

    houseSideSptepTwo.IsVisible = false;
    houseSideSptepThree.IsVisible = false;
    houseSideSptepFour.IsVisible = false;
}
```

In debug I can see that the button click hits the command and the HouseSideStep value increments, but on the UI no changes.

Previous I did this in code, and that worked from the button event and setting the visible property of each HorizontalStackLayout.

thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a Maui bug related to DataTrigger and a view that has IsVisible=False when the page is first drawn.

As a test, try this. It will show them all at first (which I know you don't want), but if it works, that helps isolate the problem:

```cs
public DetailedDataPage(DetailedDataViewModel DetailedDataViewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = DetailedDataViewModel;

    // --- remove this. Start with #2 visible ---
    //houseSideSptepTwo.IsVisible = false;
}
```

````xml
<DataTrigger TargetType="HorizontalStackLayout"
             Binding="{Binding HouseSideSptep}"
             Value="1">
    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger TargetType="HorizontalStackLayout"
             Binding="{Binding HouseSideSptep}"
             Value="2">
    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
</DataTrigger>

...
... similar logic on #2, but with values "2" => True, "3" => false ...
```xaml

The idea of the test is to see if an element that starts visible, can be made to hide.

If this works, then your original problem is definitely a Maui bug, involving IsVisible and DataTrigger.

If it works, then with appropriate triggers, the bug can be worked around:

1. Start with everything visible.
2. Start with `houseSideSptep = 0;`, which we will force to change in step 4.
3. Add DataTriggers that hide #2, #3, #4, when HouseSideSptep is 1.
4. At end of constructor, add:
```cs
Dispatcher.Dispatch( async() =>
{
    await Task.Delay(500);   // HACK to make sure page has displayed. TBD a better way to run code after a page is displayed.
    HouseSideSptep  = 1;
});
````

Comment: I agree this is a bug, I tried every possible way I know, and it not worked.